# Как отсортировать массив в numpy по ключу?

Tags: python, numpy

Я пытаюсь разобраться, как работать с numpy и хочу отсортировать одномерный массив по ключу-функции, примерно так:

```
a = [9, 0, 3, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0]
a.sort(key=bool)
>>>[0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 3, 8, 1]
```

Есть ли способ подобной сортировки массива в numpy, без конвертации в обычный список и обратно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([9, 0, 3, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0])

def key(a):
    return a != 0

print(a[np.argsort(key(a))])
```

https://ideone.com/lIbvaN

Comment: Можно сделать короче: `print(a[np.argsort(a.astype(bool))])`

Comment: @CrazyElf, знаю, но решил сделать пример с функцией